# Can I do a smooth resize animation on a control with only a 2 size increase

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

**I want to have a control (button) to have a smooth resizing animation, although the problem is that you can only set the size of a control to a int (whole) value, which won't make it a smooth animation.**
So is there anyway I can achieve a smooth resize animation with only a 2 increase in size?
*For example, the buttons in the Windows 10 settings application when you let go of a button and how they have a smooth animation, although the resize is very small.*

Comment: You can increase the time that is taken to display the animation, that will smoothen it out but three end value of a size should be a whole number because you can't use part of a pixel for display

Comment: But with a 2 size difference, it can only move from 2, 1, 0, but I want it to be a very smooth animation. For example, how the buttons in the Windows 10 settings app gradually resize

Comment: Also for animation like that, I'd suggest to use wpf not win forms.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The Control.Size structure does not take floating-point values, but rather Int32.  Pixels or points, but always integer.
 [Reference here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size(v=vs.110).aspx)